# Django submitting many to one relation models

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a Django application with relation to exercises per workout.

I currently have two tables, one that stores exercise (multiple exercises per workout) information, and one that stores the workout information with a **workout** that is a **foreign key** between the two.

However, I'm having trouble grasping the concept of submitting multiple exercises inside of one form without it getting fairly ugly very fast.

Keep in mind I am a Django noob so feel free to point out any redundant or useless code you see

Models.py

```
class workout(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , db_column='userid')

    datesubmitted = models.DateField() 
    workoutdate = models.DateField(); 
    bodyweight = models.FloatField(null=True);
    totalreps = models.IntegerField() 
    totalweight = models.FloatField()
    numsets = models.IntegerField(); 
    numexercises = models.IntegerField()
    workoutname = models.CharField(max_length=250) 

    def getallexercises (self,id):
        all_workout_exercises = exercise.objects.filter(workoutid = id)
        return all_workout_exercises
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/home"

class workoutForm(ModelForm): 

    class Meta:

        model = workout
        exclude = ('user','bodyweight','totalreps','totalweight','datesubmitted')



class exercise(models.Model):
    workout = models.ForeignKey(workout,db_column='workoutid')  
    userid = models.IntegerField();

    exercisename = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    repetitions = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.FloatField() 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/home"



class exerciseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = exercise
```

views.py

```
class workoutCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = workoutForm
    model = workout 

    def form_valid(self,form):
        createxercise(self.request,self.model.pk)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user; 
        form.instance.bodyweight = self.request.POST['weight']
        form.instance.datesubmitted = datetime.datetime.now()
        form.instance.totalweight = summation(list(self.request.POST['weightinputboxes']))
        form.instance.totalreps = summation(list(self.request.POST['repinputboxes']))
        return super(workoutCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Where should I attempt to submit the exercises? I've read about **inlineformset_factory** but I'm not sure if I can make this work for creating multiple exercise rows in my table...

Thanks for the help guys, I appreciate it!

Comment: off topic, but as a matter of style (since you said you were new to django), [PEP 8 recommends CamelCasing your class names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modelformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) is what you need. Look at the documentation, which has good examples explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not ask a specific question, but here a few things to clean up your code:

1. By convention, class names in Python use CapWords (initial caps on each word). [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) provides the style guide for Python.
2. You don't need the `getallexercises` method, django provides methods to do [relationship lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward). For your case, if `w` was a workout instance, you can do `w.exercise_set.all()`
3. You should also avoid hard coding urls in `get_absolute_url`, consider using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) along with [naming your url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

Finally, you are on the right track with `inlineformset_factory`.